# Comparing files and seeing the differences

Tags: excel, compare, vlookup

I've two excel files having data and each having four columns. I need to compare the two excels and it should show me the difference for each row.

To achieve this, I'm  thinking of:

1. Using a VLookup feature

or

2. Writing Python code to achieve this.

Was wondering if there is any other better approach for this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

```
Here is an example of how you could use the =IF function to compare two Excel files:

1. Open both Excel files in separate tabs in Excel.

2. In the first Excel file, select the cell where you want to display the result of the comparison.

3. Type the =IF function in the selected cell, followed by the cell reference for the corresponding cell in the second Excel file. For example, if you want to compare the values in cell A1 of the first Excel file with cell A1 of the second Excel file, you would type =IF(A1=Sheet2!A1, "Match", "Difference") in the selected cell.

4. Press Enter to execute the =IF function and display the result of the comparison. If the values in the two cells are the same, the =IF function will display "Match". If the values are different, the =IF function will display "Difference".

5. Repeat the above steps for each cell that you want to compare in the two Excel files. And when you've done it to two you mgiht be able to select the two created IF's and drag it down so it will fill out the rest (if you someday have more than 4 columns).
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frederick! I shall try this approach.